# What does "her" in "daher" or "über 10 Jahre her" mean?

Tags: grammar-identification

> Das ist schon über 10 Jahre **her**.

What is the use of **her** here?

Comment: Your sentence would translate to english: *It is more than 10 years **ago***

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/her

Answer (score 4):

> Das ist über 10 Jahre her [*It's been more than 10 years that ...*]

`her` expresses that the referenced events have been concluded at the specified time in the past or at least they have been out of focus since then. It suggests that something is given attention to that has already been brought or come to an end and that one would not expect to be unwrapped again.

`daher` has several related meanings denoting the origin, literally in a spatial ( `from there` ) and figuratively in a causal ( `for this reason` ) reading. It does not directly mirror a temporal relationship, though spatial and causal dependencies naturally imply one.

According to the [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/her), the meaning of `her` can be analyzed etymologically as `from there to here` in the sense of a movement towards the position of the speaker/writer, and thus figuratively a period or effect reaching from some point of time in the past to the present.

***Example (`her`, temporal)***

Compare

> Das I-Phone war das erste Smartphone. Vor über 10 Jahren kam es auf den Markt.
>   [The I phone was the first smartphone. It was introduced more than 10 years ago]

with

> Der Apple II war der erste Homecomputer. Das ist jetzt über 40 Jahre her.
>   [The Apple 2 was the first home computer. It's been more than 40 years now]

While smartphones (and in particular Apple's) have been a hot topic ever since, the Apple 2 is of historical interest only today.

Comment: Could you please add something about “her” in “daher”, too.